# Will i be granted ESTA after getting rejected thrice on different nationality?

Tags: usa, visa-refusals, esta

I had applied for B1/B2 on my previous nationality but it got rejected **Thrice**. 
I had planned on visiting my mother as she lives there. my last refusal was 3 years back. Now i have gained an European nationality and I am thinking of applying for ESTA so I can visit my mother. I have doubts if it will be accepted because I'll have to disclose about my previous refusals.

What should I do? because if I don't disclose my previous refusals I fear I might be rejected permanently.

Comment: @HankyPanky if the ESTA is granted after disclosing the prior visa refusals, why would there be trouble at the border?

Answer (score 3):

> what should i do?

Apply for ESTA, disclosing your other citizenship and prior visa refusals when asked.

> [Why?]

You have nothing to lose but $4 (the $10 portion of the fee is charged only for successful applications, for a total of $14; a refusal costs only $4).

This is because we know nothing about the reasons for your previous visa refusals.  If they came about because of some technical problems in your applications, for example, then the ESTA might well be granted.  On the other hand, if we knew that you had been found permanently inadmissible for some reason, then an ESTA application would be a waste of time.  But we don't know anything like that, and the cost of trying is rather low at $4 plus a few minutes of your time.

> [What if the ESTA is refused?]

Then apply for a B visa.  Consider coming back here to see whether we can shed any more light on your past refusals.  This might help you submit a successful application.  Or, if you can afford it, consult with a reputable US immigration lawyer.

Comment: Isn't the ESTA automatically refused if he discloses previous visa refusals?

Comment: @TomasBy No.  Statutory grounds for disqualification from the VWP include prior VWP violations, but not prior visa refusals.  See for example [ESTA approved on the same day as B-1/B-2 visa refused](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/61059/19400) (unfortunately, the links are broken), and the suggested duplicate question.  See also [My ESTA approved after being refused a US visa](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g1-i10702-k9156057-My_ESTA_approved_after_being_refused_a_US_visa-Air_Travel.html) on tripadvisor.

Comment: Downvoter, please explain.